# How can I extract version from a file name in Ant without using ant contrib?

Tags: ant

I am trying to scan a folder in ant script and extract the version out of it, suppose file name is **abc-1.0.0.exe/dmg**. I want to get the **1.0.0** in Ant. Is there any way I can do without using ant contrib?  I only found help with ant contrib which I don't want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use something like this, based on the [`<pathconvert>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) with a regexmapper.

Here's the directory structure in this example:

```
$ find folder
folder
folder/abc-1.0.0.exe
folder/abc-1.0.0.exe/dmg
```

Here's the Ant buildfile:

```
<fileset dir="folder" id="folder"/>

<echo message="file is: ${toString:folder}" />

<pathconvert property="version">
    <path path="${toString:folder}" />
    <regexpmapper from=".*-(.*).exe.*" to="\1" />
</pathconvert>

<echo message="version is: ${version}" />
```

Output:

```
 [echo] file is: abc-1.0.0.exe/dmg
 [echo] version is: 1.0.0
```